# how to compare and merge two xml using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, merge

I want to compare two xmls and then merge them. For example:

myFile1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<catalog>
<data>
    <title>Title1</title>
    <description>Description1</description>
    <myid>1</myid>
</data>
<data>
    <title>Title2</title>
    <description>Description2</description>
    <myid>2</myid>
</data>
</catalog>
```

myFile2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<catalog>
<data>
    <title>Title1</title>
    <description>Description1</description>
    <author>Author1</author>
    <date>12/34/5678</date>
    <myid>1</myid>
</data>
<data>
    <author>Author2</author>
    <date>87/65/4321</date>
    <myid>2</myid>
</data>
</catalog>
```

Desired Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<catalog>
<data>
    <title>Title1</title>
    <description>Description1</description>
    <myid>1</myid>
    <author>Author1</author>
    <date>12/34/5678</date>
</data>
<data>
    <title>Title2</title>
    <description>Description2</description>
    <myid>2</myid>
    <author>Author2</author>
    <date>87/65/4321</date>
</data>
</catalog>
```

I have a code but, it doesnot perform as per the required output.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:variable name="compare" select="'myFile1.xml'"/>
<xsl:variable name="with" select="'myFile2.xml'"/>
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        <xsl:variable name="info1" select="document($compare)/catalog/data[myid=current()/myid]/."/>
        <xsl:variable name="info2" select="document($with)/catalog/data[myid=current()/myid]/."/>
        <xsl:for-each select="$info1/*">
            <xsl:variable name="check1" select="name(current())"/>
            <!--xsl:text>Current node1 : </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="$check1"/-->
            <xsl:for-each select="$info2/*">
                <xsl:variable name="check2" select="name(current())"/>
                <!--xsl:text>Current node2 : </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="$check2"/-->
                <xsl:if test="$check1!=$check2">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Please Help!

Comment: How do you match nodes between the two documents? Just by their position? I mean first node on doc1 must be merged with first node on doc2? Or by `myid`?

Comment: No it is matching with `myid`, not by their position. If you just change the order of the `<data>` fields, then it will copy the fields from second doc accordingly.

Comment: I see, I'm trying a different approach from your. May be you will see my answer.

Comment: Yeah sure. Actually I am new to xslt so I couldn't think of any other approach. Anything that works would be much appriciated.

Comment: See my answer now. I've done some test and it seems working.

Comment: Does matter the order of the nodes on the result tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution is totally free of loops or keys. I've loaded only one document using `document()`, while I use the other one as source. Briefly, an element missing in the source document, it is taken on the loaded one. More elements you have less usable is this solution. See bottom for a more general one.

---

**XSLT 1.0** tested on **Saxon-HE 9.2.1.1J**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:variable name="catalog2" select="document('source_test2.xml')/catalog"/>

    <xsl:template match="catalog">
        <catalog>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="data"/>
        </catalog>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="data">
        <xsl:variable name="data2" select="$catalog2/data[myid=current()/myid]/."/>
        <data>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="title">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="title"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="$data2/title"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>

            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="description">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="description"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="$data2/description"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>

            <xsl:copy-of select="myid"/>

            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="author">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="author"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="$data2/author"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>

            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="date">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="date"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="$data2/date"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>

        </data>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Here follows a more general solution. The approach is the same. For each `data`, an element present in `myFile2` and missing in `myFile1` is added to the result tree, and vice-versa.

**XSLT 1.0** tested on **Saxon-B 9.0.0.4J**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:variable name="catalog2" select="document('myFile2.xml')/catalog"/>

    <xsl:template match="catalog">
        <catalog>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="data"/>
        </catalog>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="data">
        <xsl:variable name="data1" select="."/>
        <xsl:variable name="data2" select="$catalog2/data[myid=current()/myid]/."/>
        <data>
            <xsl:copy-of select="$data1/*"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="$data2/*">
                <xsl:variable name="element2" select="name(.)"/>
                <xsl:if test="count($data1/*[name()=$element2])=0">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </data>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but this would be a schema specific, right? What if I have a large schema with more than 1000 elemnts. It won't be a feasible approach then. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Yes, more elements you have, and less usable is this approach. But I was not able to figure out another approach. May be in the next days. Please if you find a solution post it here as answer.

Comment: I've added a more general solution. Note that the elements order might be compromised in some cases. This is hard to fix as the source schema is unknown by your assumptions. Hope this help anyway.

Comment: I guess this might work. Well actually the source schema is quite huge. I will have to make some modifications, but this could work. Thanks a lot. I will let you know once I get the results.

Comment: Yeah, this has worked fine till now. Thanks a lot for the solution, will let you know if I have any problem further. Thanks once again.