# XSLT sum by lookup value from another file

Tags: xslt, sum, lookup

I want to get the total of a specific student from following 2 XML files:

--- File: `mark.xml` ----

```
<marks>
  <mark type="HD">10</mark>
  <mark type="D">8</mark>
  <mark type="C">5</mark>
</marks>
```

--- File: `studentRecord.xml` ---

```
<students>
  <student id="1234">
    <grade>HD</grade>
  </student>
  <student id="1234">
    <grade>C</grade>
  </student>
  <student id="1111">
    <grade>D</grade>
  </student>
</students>
```

How can I get the total mark of the student having `id 1234`? it should be 15.

Comment: What programming environment/technology are you using?

Comment: Does XSLT do multi-file querying? I thought you needed XQuery (or some host environment) for that. Is it practical to first combine the two documents into one?

Comment: Good question. +1. See my answer for a complete, short and easy XSLT solution that is actually a one-liner XPath expression.

Comment: Was my answer useful to you? Considering to accept the best answer?

Answer (score 3):

**Here is a short and easy XSLT solution** (actually it is just XPath):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:my="my:my">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <my:MarkValues>
        <marks>
            <mark type="HD">10</mark>
            <mark type="D">8</mark>
            <mark type="C">5</mark>
        </marks>
 </my:MarkValues>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
     <xsl:value-of select=
     "sum(document('')/*
           /my:MarkValues/*/*
               [@type = current()/*
                          [@id='1234']/grade
             ]
        )"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied to the provided XML document** (named "studentRecord.xml") :

```
<students>
    <student id="1234">
        <grade>HD</grade>
    </student>
    <student id="1234">
        <grade>C</grade>
    </student>
    <student id="1111">
        <grade>D</grade>
    </student>
</students>
```

**the wanted answer is produced**:

```
15
```

**If you want to keep the marks values in a separate file** (not embedded into the XSLT stylesheet as above), **the XPath expression should be slightly changed** (just the argument to the `document()` function:

```
sum(document('mark.xml')/*/*
                     [@type = current()/*
                                     [@id='1234']/grade
                     ]
   )
```

**Explanation**:

1. Using the XSLT **[`document()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#function-document)** function.
2. Using the XSLT **[`current()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#function-current)** function.
3. Using the XPath **[`sum()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-sum)** function.

Comment: thanks for this **XPath** trick. I was wandering if it was possible. That's why my answer is slightly different (and may be silly). If you have time and pleasure, I'd like to know your opinion (or answer as well) about this other [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6047505/how-to-compare-and-merge-two-xml-using-xslt/). Thanks again for sharing your knowledge.

Comment: @empo: You are welcome. I hope that you don't hate my comments to your solution... :)

Answer (score 0):

In the following transform I build first a variable with the gathered values and then XPath `sum()` function is used to get the result. It's not as elegant and smart as @Dimitre approach but I'd like to post anyway :)

---

**XSLT 2.0** tested under **Saxon-HE 9.2.1.1J**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>   

    <xsl:variable name="lookup" select="document('lookup.xml')/marks"/> 

    <xsl:template match="students">

        <xsl:variable name="values">
            <values>
                <xsl:for-each select="student[@id='1234']">
                    <value><xsl:value-of select="$lookup/mark[@type=current()/grade]"/></value>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </values>
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:value-of select="sum($values//value)"/>

    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result applied on the input data provided in the question is just the sum:

```
 15
```

Comment: This isn't an "XSLT 1.0" solution -- never make any conclusions based on the fact that a a supposedly XSLT 1.0 transformation is run successfully with an XSLT 2.0 processor. Try it with Saxon 6.5.x, MSXMLx, .NET XslCompiledTransform or any other XSLT 1.0 - compliant XSLT processor. Then fix your mistake, or better, think of a better solution. Please, note: I am *not* downvoting you. I believe that our participation in SO is a learning experience and would be glad to see everyone growing up.

Comment: @Dimitre: I though that Saxon was able to process xsl according to the version specified in it. I see now the reason of the warning about version 1.0. I've tried then my solution with Saxon 6 and it fails. If I'm not wrong, in XSLT 1.0 i can't use `xsl:value-of` on node-sets like that. Thanks for your remark.

Answer (score -1):

Try this C# code:

```c#
 var studenst = XElement.Load("studentRecord.xml");
 var marks= XElement.Load("marks.xml");

 Dictionary<string, int> marksDic = new Dictionary<string, int>();
 foreach (XElement m in marks.Descendants())
      {
           if (m.Attribute("type") != null)
                marksDic.Add(m.Attribute("type").Value, int.Parse(m.Value));
      }


      foreach (XElement s in studenst.Descendants().Where(x=>(x.Attribute("id") !=null ?int.Parse(x.Attribute("id").Value):0)==id))
      {

           Console.WriteLine(marksDic.Where(x => x.Key == s.Value)
                .Select(x => x.Value).Single());
      }
 }
```