# Merging two XML files

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to merge two XML files:

1st XML:

```
<data>
  <text>
    <description>this is my description</description>
    <title>this is my title</title>
  </text>
  <text>
    <description>this <other>is my other description</other></description>
    <title>this is my title</title>
  </text>
</data>
```

2nd XML:

```
<data>
  <text>
    <description>this is my <tag>description</tag></description>
  </text>
  <text>
    <description>this is <tag>my other description</tag></description>
  </text>
</data>
```

OUPUT wanted :

```
<data>
  <text>
    <description>this is my <tag>description</tag></description>
    <title>this is my title</title>
  </text>
  <text>
    <description>this <other>is <tag>my other description</tag></other></description>
    <title>this is my title</title>
  </text>
</data>
```

I used and adapted the XSLT given here :
[how to compare and merge two xml using xslt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6047505/how-to-compare-and-merge-two-xml-using-xslt)

But I can't add together OTHER and TAG into DESCRIPTION.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please see following link:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15175287/how-to-merge-two-xml-files

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, it seems to be a different problem in my case: I need to combine the tags and not replace a value.